# How to show the status of restaurant open or closed in react

Tags: reactjs, django

I have a "openTime" and "closeTime" variable which stores the opening and closing time of restaurants respectively. And I want to display the status of the restaurant "open" or "closed" in react . How can I do this

Comment: Can you add some part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can have three date objects,

pseudocode:

```
D1 = new Date(); //current Time, you can manipulate this acc. to expected date format
D2 = new Date(openTime);
D3 = new Date(closeTime);
if (D1.getTime() <= D3.getTime() && D1.getTime() >= D2.getTime()) { 
   //change state accordingly and show open
} else { 
   //change state accordingly and show close
}
```